# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' and I can't find out why

Tags: php

```
    echo ($x == $page) ? '
     <br/>
     <html>
     <head>
     <link href="homecss/pagination.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
     </head>
     <body>
     <b>
     <a href="?page=".$x."">".$x."</a></b> ":" <a href="?page=".$x."">".$x."</a>
     </body>
     </html>';
```

^ That's only part of a script I'm using with Pagination, it works fine with only this code: 
`echo ($x == $page) ? 
'<b><a href="?page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a></b> ':'<a href="?page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a>  ';`

and I can't find the errors, as soon as I remove the ? after ($x == $page) it sorta works but still prints out errors, and plus I need the ? there.

[NOTE] The only reason I added all the HTML tags is so i can use CSS to style the pagination buttons...

Comment: You're doing wrong concatenation here. Use `"'.$x.'"`.

Comment: What you are doing is wrong, the (codition)?out1:out2; is for simple logic, if you see, you are lost in the code because is to big, is better une one simple if else, and the problem in your logic is because you have the `":"` is one big `' '`, and if you fix the problem and you put `"':'"` you will have a bad html syntax (and if you see you have to put `page='.$x.'">'.$x.` not  `page=.$x.">.$x.`  )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
 echo ($x == $page) ? '
 <br/>
 <html>
 <head>
 <link href="homecss/pagination.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
 <b>
 <a href="?page=".$x."">".$x."</a></b> ":" <a href="?page=".$x."">".$x."</a>
 </body>
 </html>';
```

to

```
     echo ($x == $page) ? '
 <br/>
 <html>
 <head>
 <link href="homecss/pagination.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
 <b>
 <a href="?page="'.$x.'">"'.$x.'"</a></b>"'. : .'" <a href="?page="'.$x.'">"'.$x.'"</a>

 </body>
 </html>';
```

Comment: Because it's a required part of the ternary operator syntax - see the PHP website link in my answer.

Comment: I get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';' for the } I have below the code now..

Comment: @Ayyanar G Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ',' or ';' is the error I get after adding ' : '';

EDIT: the correct answer is ' ; ''; I believe cause I changed it to that and it worked fine

Answer (score 1):

The [PHP ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) requires a `:` condition.

In your code, you can add a `: '';` after the first condition.

```
</html>' : '';
```

Here's [the example from the PHP website](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

```
// Example usage for: Ternary Operator
$action = (empty($_POST['action'])) ? 'default' : $_POST['action'];
```

You can read more about [the ternary operator on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:).

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing single and double quotes.
You started with a single quote but then went on as if expecting double quotes. It does not work that way.

If you use double quotes **"** you can just type variables inline `"hello $world";` and it will parse the value of `$world` in the string.

If you use single quotes you can type whatever you want in the string it won't parse it. you need to concatenate in that case.

`'hello " $world';` = *hello " $world*. To get the value in this case it would be `'hello'.$world;`

Now for your binary operation you alway have this:

- (boolean/if condition) **?** What to **return** if true **:** what  to **return** if false;

The colon **:** is what seperates the return values.

```
$x="SOMETHING";
echo ($x == $page) ? '
     <br/>
     <html>
     <head>
     <link href="homecss/pagination.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
     </head>
     <body>
     <b>
     <a href="?page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a></b> ': ' <a href="?page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a>
     </body>
     </html>';
```